# Android Mediplayer not playing music

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to play a song that is in remote server and is in this link. You also can check the song. but as per what i have coded the song is not getting played from the remote server.

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try{

        mySong = new MediaPlayer();
        mySong.setDataSource("http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3");
        mySong.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mySong.prepareAsync();
        mySong.start();     

        }
        catch(Exception ee){
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(ee.getMessage());
        }
        finally{
            mySong.reset();
            mySong.release();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see specific problem here. Please provide relevant logs.

Answer (score 1):

are you serious?
You are starting it just to reset and release it instantly?find the wrong logic!

Or do you think the finally statement will be executed after the song is played through?

Answer (score 1):

You call prepareAsync() in your code. Because you are preparing asynchronously, you're going to receive a callback called `onPrepared(MediaPlayer)` after you've declared that your Activity implements `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener`. It is here that you should be calling `mySong.start()`. Calling it right after `prepareAsync` would most likely cause an IllegalStateException to occur because the MediaPlayer isn't prepared yet. Finally, you'll want to set a `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` so you can release the MediaPlayer there instead of the finally block. Also, resetting the MediaPlayer and releasing is redundant. If you're going to release it right away, there's no reason to reset it.